# How to create a background effect

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, css-animations

First of all I apologize if the question is too broad to answer, but I just need the direction for approach.
How to create a background animation like ( the red stripe background ) : [link](https://trionndesign.com/)

I am learning css animation, and wanted to know the direction I  can approach to get the effect like this.

Answer (score 0):

They do not really animate all kinds of swirls, it's the pattern that makes you mind think it does. It is a background image that animates up and down :)

Possible solution with the image as background (but anything that moves could work):

```
#example{
  background-image: url('https://trionndesign.com/images/creativeBg.jpg');
  animation-name: backgroundscroller;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes backgroundscroller {
   from { background-position:    0  0; }
   to {   background-position:  100% 0; }
}
```

---

A lot of non-endless-repeating animations work with a before and an after. It starts with 0 scroll and ends with 100% scrolled. Or 0 opacity to 1 opacity. The trick is to figure that out, what is the property they're animating and apply it with css' `transition`.

In case of endless animation, you need the more advanced example like above.

Comment: they are animating the background with animate name `cbg-pos-move`

Comment: added it to my answer. Just toy around with transition, add all kinds of funky stuff and see what happens. Thats how you create funny animations